# sync my webmail 'SENT' folder with Thunderbird

Tags: sync, thunderbird, imap, webmail

I want to sync my webmail 'SENT' folder with Thunderbird, both Yahoo and Hotmail. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Set your Hotmail account to forward mail to Yahoo!.  Then use IMAP to sync Thunderbird with Yahoo! mail.  As far as I know, Hotmail doesn't offer IMAP access, so you can't sync with it without buying third-party software like IzyMail.

Never log on to Hotmail again, just read all your mail in Thunderbird or Yahoo!.

Answer (score 0):

Some mail servers allow
`username@domain.com-SENT`
or
`username+sent_items@domain.com`
to grab the sent foler